# How can I protect refresh_token which generated by AWS Cognito for Single Page Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, single-page-application

I am planning to create a single page web application and all user authentication would be handled by AWS Cognito. By reading through some of articals, they all suggest using "code" grant flow + PKCE rather than implicit flow since implicit flow is deprecated in OAuth 2.1

I created a test user pool with AWS Cognito, by using Postman I successfully get access_token, id token and refresh token with code grant flow + PKCE.

I double checked with AWS Cognito Doc, seems refresh token will always be returned if using code grant flow and I cannot find anywhere in AWS console to disable returning refresh token. So just wondering how can I protect refresh_token? Cookie or localStorage can not stop XSS.

Answer (score 1):

It is usual to route requests for tokens via a backend, eg a utility API, which also represents the refresh token as an `HTTP Only SameSite=strict encrypted secure cookie`. See [this crypto code](https://github.com/curityio/oauth-agent-node-express/blob/master/src/lib/cookieEncrypter.ts) for an example.

The backend component also enables you to use a client secret, in addition to PKCE, which improves security a little. Cognito supports this, so I'd recommend using both.

**BEST PRACTICE**

[OAuth for browser based apps](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps#section-6.2) recommends this approach. Stakeholders often expect you to be using the backend for frontend described, and it will make life more comfortable if you have to explain your app's security.

**XSS**

With the above HTTP only cookie approach, malicious code would not be able to steal your refresh tokens, and this is therefore the recommended way to handle them.

If your SPA has XSS vulnerabilities, then malicious code might be able to steal your data though, regardless of whether tokens or cookies are used to access data. Therefore it is critical to implement XSS protection carefully, regardless of your OAuth solution.

Comment: Hi Gary, thank you for your answer! My original plan was to create a SPA app and it will talk with a serverless API (aws gateway+lambda). After reading your suggestion, I would happy to follow the Best practice and will take sometime to dig which AWS service suit for the Best practice eg: aws amplify? maybe.